# Apply background to span - but NOT where the text is

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header style on my page, where after the header text, for the rest of the column, a decoration is applied.

I have the style created, and it is getting applied to my header.

```
header3 {
    font-family:'Orbitron', san-serif;
    color:#7c7e82;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        #d63c09,
        #d63c09 5px,
        #fff 5px,
        #fff 10px
    );
}
```

The style is applied, but it is also behind/over the text. I would like there to be either a white background behind the text, or for the background to not be applied to it. This is what I have so far:

[image: The OP's problem]

What I want is the following style:

[image: What OP actually wants (based on his desc.)]

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for. Could you at least post a [mcve]?

Comment: maybe include your html code for the header?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it currently looks like, and point out how you want it to be different?

Comment: You can try to use pseudo element like ::after and style its background

Answer (score 2):

You could also do the following, it does not change most of your code, but adds a new class to your header `h1` tag.

So basically, set the new class, `header` in this case, to a new background color of choice and then adjust the `width` property in css.

```css
.header3 {
    font-family:'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    color:#7c7e82;
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        45deg,
        #d63c09,
        #d63c09 5px,
        #fff 5px,
        #fff 10px
    );
}

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header3">
  <h1 class="header">Test Header</h1>
</div>
```

A second version to this, for example if you want your header to be engulfed in the background decoration, use `display: inline` property in CSS.

```css
.outer {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #d63c09, #d63c09 5px, #fff 5px, #fff 10px);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.inner {
  display: inline;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #7c7e82;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>Test Header</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make something like this:

You have a background for the entire header, but the text has its own.

```css
.outer{background:orange;padding:3rem}
.inner{background:white;padding:1rem}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Lorem Ipsum dolor sit Amet</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think i might have gotten it - using what Jakub Posted helped me:
    outer{
        background:repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #d63c09,
    #d63c09 5px,
    #fff 5px,
    #fff 10px
  );
    }
    .phb .inner{
     display:inline;
        background:#fff;
        font-size:1em;
 color:#7c7e82;
        padding:5px;
  font-family:'Orbitron', san-serif
    } 


<div class='outer'>
<div class='inner'>Skills</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your font - it should be `sans-serif` not `san-serif`.